DataView RowFilter date time with XML
I have xml feed as
<CalendarEvent>
<EventID>12667274</EventID>
<StartDate>14/11/2024</StartDate>
<StartTime>08:45</StartTime>
<EndDate>14/11/2024</EndDate>
<EndTime>09:15</EndTime>
<Title>Hello Title</Title>
<Location>Room 1</Location>
</CalendarEvent>

Following line shows all the events in Room 1.
dv.RowFilter = "Location='Room 1'";

How can I show all the events after the current time
dv.RowFilter = "(StartTime >= 'DateTime.Now.ToString(HH:mm)";

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

What is the type of StartTime column? Is it a string, DateTime, TimeOnly?

its from xml feed and it has time only

Try this
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;  

string currentDate = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");  
string currentTime = now.ToString("HH:mm");  


dv.RowFilter = $"(StartDate > '{currentDate}' OR (StartDate = '{currentDate}' AND StartTime > '{currentTime}'))";


it works, thank you
